# How can I use type-traits to make this array-to-pointer conversion unambiguous?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I would like to discern between static arrays and pointers.

The following example fails to compile due to **array-to-pointer conversions having exact match**, making both `foo`'s possible candidates.

Am I able to get the 2nd overload of `foo` to be unambiguously selected using type traits?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void foo(const T* str)
{
    std::cout << "ptr: " << str << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
void foo(const T (&str)[N])
{
    std::cout << "arr: " << str << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo("hello world"); // I would like the array version to be selected
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try SFINAE with `std::is_array`

Comment: @Steve: this compiles under linux with 'g++' and 'g++ --std=c++0x'. The array version is selected by both compilations.
g++ = 4.6.3
linux =  3.11.0-26

Comment: @vincent - gcc-4.8.2 gives `error: call of overloaded ‘foo(const char [12])’ is ambiguous`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value,void>::type
foo(const T str)
{
    std::cout << "ptr: " << str << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
void
foo(const T (&str)[N])
{
    std::cout << "arr: " << str << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Compiles, but selects the 1st overload. (ie: prints `ptr: hello world`). That's because `T` is `char`, which is not an array.

Comment: @sp2danny: You should use `std::is_pointer<T>::value` instead of `!std::is_array<T>::value` to disallow `foo(42)`.

Answer (score 9):

You may use the following:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T> struct foo;

    template <typename T>
    struct foo<T*>
    {
        void operator()(const T* str) {std::cout << "ptr: " << str << std::endl;}
    };

    template <typename T, std::size_t N>
    struct foo<T [N]>
    {
        void operator()(const T (&str)[N]) {std::cout << "arr: " << str << std::endl;}
    };
}

template<typename T>
void foo(const T& t)
{
    detail::template foo<T>()(t);
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/Wn5Yjb)

Comment: Woah - nice! Please could you add some details on how this is working?

Comment: The reference take the exact type, and then a simple dispatch to the correct specialization does the job.