# Why is the "universal reference" overload being selected instead of the char array or char pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, type-traits

I want to unpack a variadic template pack and select a particular overload based on each type in the pack.

I have 3 overloads for unpacking various types:

```
    // fixed size char arrays
    template<size_t N, typename... Ts>
    void unpack(const char (&)[N], Ts&&... ts);

    // char pointers
    template<typename... Ts>
    void unpack(const char*, Ts&&... ts);

    // all other types
    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    void unpack(T&&, Ts&&... ts);
```

I'm passing a char array (`char buf[1024]`) as an lvalue to the variadic constructor. When unpacking the pack, the `T&&` overload is being selected.

How can I get the `const char (&)[N]` or `const char*` overload selected?

**Example app:**

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    template<typename... Ts>
    foo(Ts&&... ts)
    {
        unpack(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }

    template<size_t N, typename... Ts>
    void unpack(const char (&)[N], Ts&&... ts)
    {
        std::cout << "const T (&)[N]" << std::endl;
        unpack(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }

    template<typename... Ts>
    void unpack(const char*, Ts&&... ts)
    {
        std::cout << "const char*" << std::endl;
        unpack(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    void unpack(T&&, Ts&&... ts)
    {
        std::cout << "T&&" << std::endl;
        unpack(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }

    void unpack()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    char buf[1024];
    const char* str = "foo";
    foo f(buf, str);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code results in the following being printed:

```
T&&
const char*
```

I would like it to print either:

```
const T (&)[N]
const char*
```

or

```
const char*
const char*
```

ie: select one of the two char overloads - array or pointer.

Comment: Similar to [how-to-make-this-array-to-pointer-conversion-unambiguous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880716/how-can-i-use-type-traits-to-make-this-array-to-pointer-conversion-unambiguous)

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried that! It was the above problem that lead me to ask the previous question... the problem is not ambiguity between the char array and char pointer - it's selecting the `T&&` overload.

Comment: The same solutions may also apply here: use SFINAE to restrict what `T&&` catch or use specialization on classes.

Comment: @Jarod42 - yes, thanks - I got that from @user657267's answer - the fact that the `char`s are not `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is removing the array overload and just use

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, char>::value> unpack(T*, Ts&&... ts)
{
    std::cout << "(const) char*" << std::endl;
    unpack(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}
```

This is enabled only if `T` is deduced to be (possibly cv-qualified) `char` (meaning it's a perfect match for both `char *` and `const char *` as the first parameter), and in those cases it's more specialized than the base template, and hence selected by overload resolution.

Replace `enable_if_t` and `decay_t` with the more verbose `typename /*...*/::type` if not using C++14.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8c8252c0dfd78bf).

Answer (score 5):

`void unpack(T&&, Ts&&... ts)` is selected because the `char`s in your `buf` array are not `const`.

If you change `buf` to `char const buf[1024]{};` the compiler will tell you that the call is ambiguous, which is a step in the right direction. From there you will probably need to use SFINAE (e.g. `std::is_array`), `std::decay` or some other method to disambiguate the call.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that the const played a part in the overload resolution.

Comment: @SteveLorimer indeed, although top-level qualifiers *don't*, so for instance with `char const* const` the final `const` is irrelevant for resolution purposes.

Comment: @user657267 unless! `f(char const* const&)` ;)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Since there's no such thing as a cv-qualified reference, and the final const in that type refers to the * (i.e. it is not a top-level cv-qualifier), the statement still holds.

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_array<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value>::type
unpack(T&&, Ts&&... ts)
{
    std::cout << "T&&" << std::endl;
    unpack(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}
```

Note: that currently forbids any array and not just array of char.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, instead of specifically testing for arrays / pointers, you could check for a match to your earlier overloads:

```
int unpack_helper(...);

// fixed size char arrays
template<size_t N, typename... Ts>
void unpack_helper(const char (&)[N], Ts&&... ts);

// char pointers
template<typename... Ts>
void unpack_helper(const char*, Ts&&... ts);

// fixed size char arrays
template<size_t N, typename... Ts>
void unpack(const char (&)[N], Ts&&... ts);

// char pointers
template<typename... Ts>
void unpack(const char*, Ts&&... ts);

// all other types
template<typename T, typename... Ts, size_t = sizeof(unpack_helper(std::declval<T&&>(), std::declval<Ts&&>()...))>
void unpack(T&&, Ts&&... ts);
```

This has the possible benefit, possible drawback of also making class types with a conversion operator select your earlier function overloads.